# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <fieldset> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>. at fieldset in TextField Component material ui react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield, react-error-boundary

```
<div className="textInputTag">
      <span className="label">{props.label}</span>
      <TextField placeholder={placeholder} error={error ? true : false} defaultValue={props.defaultValue} onBlur={onBlur} onInput={onInput} type={props.type}  onFocus={onFocus}  onChange={onChange}  autoFocus={autoFocus ? autoFocus : false} disabled={props.disabled==="disabled"?true:false} value={props.value} name={props.name} className="inputTag" id={props.name} />
      <div className="errorText">{error}</div>
    </div>
```

I'm using react material ui TextField Components. But I'm getting error messages from react development tools. I have attached the error message shown in the console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MxL2.png)

I'm expecting to rectify the error from material UI textfield Component

Comment: Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-thompson-xwltdb?file=/demo.tsx, don't put a `<fieldset>` element as descendant of `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your parent elements, the error is pretty self explanatory and it can be seen that somewhere up in the DOM you have a `Typography` component that is parent of your code here.

[image]